# Parameter 2 is not registered as an output parameter

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm getting this error while running this:

```
try {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println(password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        CallableStatement cStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call login(?,?,?)}");
        cStatement.setString(1, email);
        cStatement.setString(2, password);
        cStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        cStatement.execute();

        String mail = cStatement.getString(2);
        System.out.println("your mail is:" + mail);

        response.sendRedirect("confirm.jsp");

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

    System.out.println(e + " sorry it error");
    }
```

The stored procedure is:

```
 DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `login`(IN emailName varchar(128),pass varchar(50),OUT emailid varchar(255) )
BEGIN
Select email INTO emailid from magento_user_java where email = emailName and password = pass;
END
```

please resolve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Which error you are getting?

Comment: Parameter 2 is not registered as an output parameter

Comment: emailid may be int in DB.

Comment: No, varchar(255) only

Comment: If I edit the callablestatement like this:CallableStatement cStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call login(?,?)}"); it throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `String mail = cStatement.getString(2);` has wrong parameter input.

In your stored procedure you have 3 parameters in which 3rd is an out parameter. And you have registered the same with following statement.

```
cStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

So, you can only call parameter 3 using `getXXX` methods.
Following statement may fix your issue.

```
String mail = cStatement.getString( 3 );
```

---

***Some on-line code snippets for your reference***:

**Stored Procedure**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getDBUSERByUserId(
       p_userid IN DBUSER.USER_ID%TYPE,
       o_username OUT DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE,
       o_createdby OUT  DBUSER.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
       o_date OUT DBUSER.CREATED_DATE%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN

  SELECT USERNAME , CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE
  INTO o_username, o_createdby,  o_date 
  FROM  DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = p_userid;

END;
/
```

***Calling Stored Procedure via CallableStatement***:

```
//getDBUSERByUserId is a stored procedure
String getDBUSERByUserIdSql = "{call getDBUSERByUserId(?,?,?,?)}";
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERByUserIdSql);
callableStatement.setInt(1, 10);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.DATE);

// execute getDBUSERByUserId store procedure
callableStatement.executeUpdate();

String userName = callableStatement.getString(2);
String createdBy = callableStatement.getString(3);
Date createdDate = callableStatement.getDate(4);
```

---

***Refer To***:

- [MySQL: java.sql.CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter%28int,%20int%29)
- [JDBC CallableStatement – Stored Procedure OUT Parameter Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/)